# MySQL: Omitting empty/null values from Unique Index

Tags: mysql

Consider the following data in a table

```
rowid   url
1       abc.com
2       
3       xyz.com
4       test.com
```

I can create a unique index on the url column. However, if I add another row with empty url, it will result in the Duplicate key error. Is it possible to specify a condition (e.g. not empty/not null) while creating a unique index on a column? I want to ensure that the url should be unique if entered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is difference between **NULL** and **EMPTY**.

1. Null doesn't contain any value.
2. Empty is a value of string, but is just empty.

So for database null and empty has separate meaning. 
If you want to store multiple empty records be sure that you are entering null value in table (Not empty value). MySql supports for multiple null record even if column has unique indexing, but not for empty values. For more information [Click here!](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html)

Hope this will solve your problem.